# reduce the if else on the response transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you please let me know is there any better way to write the below to avoid the if and else condition. I have a input structure is below,

```
 results=[  
 {
  "id":"11",
  "category":"Employee",
  "name":"Employe11",
  "type":"contractor"
},
 {
  "id":"11",
  "category":"Employer",
  "name":"company1",
  "count":800
},
 {
  "id":"11",
},
 {
  "name":"Employe11"
}

]
```

Have to create a new json object and I have written the below code and returning the result as expected, but thinking like there are too many if check, whether there is any way to avoid it, mainly the if conditions are to add update the dictionary only if the value exist.

```
resltlist=[]

for x in results:
  details={}
  if x.get('id', ''):
     details.update({'unique_id':x['id']})
    
  if x.get('name', ''):
     details.update({'name':x['name'])

  if x.get('type', ''):
     details.update({'emp_type':x['type'])

  if x.get('count', ''):
     details.update({'count':x['count'])
  
     if x['category']=="Employer":
        if x.get('count', ''):
          details.update({'count':x['count']})
  resultlist.append(details)

return {"results":resultlist}
```

Welcome suggestion to improve this code and whether I can reduce the if statements, thank you

Regards

Comment: So you basically just want to rename some of the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another loop, with a mapping from the results to the details dictionary

```
test=[]
mappings = { 'id':'unique_id', 'name':'name', 'type':'emp_type', 'count':'count' }
for x in results:
    details={}
    for key, value in mappings.items():
        if x.get(key, ''):
            details.update({value:x[key]})
    test.append(details)
print(test)
[{'unique_id': '11', 'name': 'Employe11', 'emp_type': 'contractor'}, {'unique_id': '11', 'name': 'company1', 'count': 800}, {'unique_id': '11'}, {'name': 'Employe11'}]
```

Comment: thanks, this works. is there any way to change the mappings when we need the name and emp_type in a nested object, like inside the 'details' inner object.

Comment: Just to clarify, are there some fields you always want in the details dict? Or some fields are needed if a particular field exists?

Answer (score 1):

A direct and fully automated way:

```
# give your rename rules here
dic_renamer = {"id": "unique_id", "type": "emp_type"}

resultlist = []
for dic in results:
    for old_name, new_name in dic_renamer.items():
        # replace old_name with new_name only if old_name exists
        if old_name in dic:
            dic[new_name] = dic[old_name]
            del dic[old_name]
    resultlist.append(dic)
```

**Result**

```
print(resultlist)

[{'category': 'Employee',
  'name': 'Employe11',
  'unique_id': '11',
  'emp_type': 'contractor'},
 {'category': 'Employer', 'name': 'company1', 'count': 800, 'unique_id': '11'},
 {'unique_id': '11'},
 {'name': 'Employe11'}]
```

Comment: thank you, this works.(sorry, choosing the other answer with the same logic as it is answered earlier. thanks much again. One more help,  is there any way to change the mappings when we need the name and emp_type in a nested object, like inside the 'details' inner object.

Comment: No problem! IMO you should accept that one indeed. For another level, I guess I would just add another for loop through dict.items(). It is natural for such a customized format to require customized parsing logic. You may post another question and describe your use case in detail.

Comment: thanks, I will try it on my end and if needed I will raise another one

Answer (score 0):

**Caution: Slow. Not suitable for >10k records or online production use.**

There is another possibility using the pandas `DataFrame()` constructor if some intermediate data analysis steps were going to take place.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results)\
    .rename(columns={"id": "unique_id", "type": "emp_type"})

print(df)
  unique_id  category       name    emp_type  count
0        11  Employee  Employe11  contractor    NaN
1        11  Employer   company1         NaN  800.0
2        11       NaN        NaN         NaN    NaN
3       NaN       NaN  Employe11         NaN    NaN
```

Output discarding NaN entries (identical to the given `resultlist` except ordering)

```
[sr.dropna().to_dict() for _, sr in df.iterrows()]  # slow!
```

Output keeping NaN entries:

```
df.to_dict(orient="records")
```